# Odoo 14 Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Dears, every time i login to the system i keep the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
http://localhost:8069/web/content/5355-ddb4341/web.assets_common.js:4981
Trace76300544747677630047676109back:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
    at Class._delegateEvents (http://localhost:8069/web/content/5355-ddb4341/web.assets_common.js:4981:164)
    at Class.update (http://localhost:8069/web/content/5355-ddb4341/web.assets_common.js:5267:33)
    at Class._check_for_tooltip (http://localhost:8069/web/content/5355-ddb4341/web.assets_common.js:5336:173)
    at Class.update (http://localhost:8069/web/content/5355-ddb4341/web.assets_common.js:5330:363)
    at _processMutations (http://localhost:8069/web/content/5355-ddb4341/web.assets_common.js:5360:72)
    at http://localhost:8069/web/content/5355-ddb4341/web.assets_common.js:5361:176
```

i install Odoo over Windows and configure it with IIS as proxy rule.

any advice to avoid this error message. & thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This might be a permission issue. Odoo tried to read the files but it's not have full access to the folder.

Try to right-click on your odoo folder files, select properties and on security tab change the file permission by adding `Everyone` to read, delete, etc.